# What does ${2:-${1}} mean in Bash?

Tags: bash

What does the following bash snippet do exactly?  ${2:-${1}}

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"Use the second argument, but if none then the first one".

Comment: And where is this documented? Is there a searchable name for this kind of construct?

Answer (score 18):

`${var:-default}` evaluates to the value of `$var`, unless `$var` isn't set in which case it evaluates to the text `"default"`. `$1`, `$2`, et al are the command-line arguments to your program (or function). Putting the two together it means to return `$2` if there were two arguments passed, otherwise return `$1`.

Answer (score 3):

It means "Use the second argument if the first is undefined *or* empty, else use the first". The form "${2-${1}}" (no ':') means "Use the second if the first is not defined (but if the first is defined as empty, use it)".

Answer (score 1):

It gives the value of ${2} if defined or defaults to ${1}
http://jaduks.livejournal.com/7934.html